# Строка по пол-размеру экрана

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-ui

## Описание

Есть у меня две текстовые объекты -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Они закрывают друг друга и чтобы они друг друга не мешали я решил поставить первый в левую половину экрана...

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

... а второй - в правую -

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

---

## Вопрос

Собственно я это делал для размеров экрана своего телефона. А как делать это для всех?
Со скриптом я конечно это могу а возможно ли это с помощью инспектора?

Comment: Вроде как у Canvas есть свойство отвечающее за автоматическое растягивание интерфейса в зависимости от размеров дисплея.

Comment: @NasltaHighborne можете сказать название?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Layout Group`

Весь ваш список является вертикальной группой.

Строка списка горизонтальной группой.

Логика заполняемости экрана и опорной точки указывается в `RectTransform`.

Что-бы контролировать размер элементов используйте `Layout Element` и галочки снизу в самом `Layout Group`.

Comment: Это не совсем вертикальный список, но компонент который вы посоветовали помог. Я использовал его немного по другому.